# Обращение к элементу по позиции в map

Tags: c++, словари, map

(Вопрос довольно таки глупый поэтому не бейте)
Вот допустим у нас есть самый обычный map:

```
map<string, int> mymap;
```

и в нем уже есть 2 элемента(ну или пары) как мне узнать ключ и значение только 2 элемента.
Есть что то на подобие:

```
std::cout << mymap[1].first << " " << mymap[1].second;
```

Comment: а что такое "второй элемент"? после помещения в мапу, пары сортируются по ключу. Может скажете, какую задачу решаете?

Comment: ну вот смотрите у меня есть определенное количевство пар(ну или элементов) и у меня по рандому выбирается число от 0 до размера map и мне надо вывести эту пару по рандомному числу

Comment: Храните это все в массиве. (std::vector<std::pair<string, int>> ).

Comment: `map` сортируется по ключам, так что "второй элемент" - это второй элемент не по порядку вставки, а второй по ключу в порядке их упорядочения. Если вам **не нужен быстрый поиск** по ключу - не используйте `map`. Если нужен - держите рядом, например, вектор с указателями на ключи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для словаря такое понятие не очень корректно, однако можно сделать так:

```
std::map<std::string, int> dict;

dict.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("a", 1));
dict.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>("b", 2));

int index = 0;
for (const auto& obj : dict)
{
    if (index == 1)
    {
        std::cout << obj.second;
        break;
    }
    index ++;
}
```

вообще в словаре есть однозначная привязка ключ-значение, а уж как именно расположены ключи - это дело десятое.

если вам как-то хочется иметь доступ по индексу к списку, то

1. или используйте индекс в качестве ключа
2. или создайте дополнительно вектор ключей и отсортируйте его по своему усмотрению, тем самым определив индексацию

P.S.

для словарей ваш вопрос выглядит примерно так:
"я ищу второй сайт с информацией о c++"

тут же будет вопрос - "что значит второй сайт", вот вам список сайтов, где есть информация, но ни один из них не имеет своего индекса (нумерацию)

гугл вам выдаст в одном порядке, яндекс - в другом

Comment: никто так в здравом уме не делает. Но если уже и нужно (ну мало чего, то используют `std::advance(it, pos)`

Comment: порядок ключей в мапе в общем случае понятен. Так что сравнение с поисковыми системами притянуто за уши

Comment: @KoVadim, порядок ключей по работе оператора `>` вроде как, но если использовать не встроенные типы, а собственные, то как я буду их порядок определять - мое дело :) кроме того (я тут могу путать) поиск по ключу - это O(log(N)), но можно сделать хэшированный словарь и будет O(1), как там ключи будут лежать - вообще непонятно (например сделать CRC8)

Comment: Если Вы определите оператор сравнения, то порядок будет очевидным. Если оператор сравнения будет выдавать что попало, то в общем случае map работать не будет. А вот "хешированный словарь" (unordered_map) - на то он и неупорядоченный, что в нем вообще нельзя говорить о взятии элемента по индексу.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен какой то `i - тый` элемент карты по порядку ключа, то просто находим по соответствующему итератору.

```
auto It = std::next(mymap.begin(), i);
cout << It->first << '\n' 
    << It->second;
```